# How can I Select all Columns of every Table in my Database whose type is of Decimal(10,0) so that i need to change to Decimal(10,2) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I Select all Columns of every Table in my Database whose type is of **Decimal(10,0)** so that I need to change to **Decimal(10,2)** in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select table_schema,table_name,column_name,data_type,numeric_precision,numeric_scale 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema='<databasename>' and data_type='decimal' and numeric_precision=10 and numeric_scale=0;
```